# Rails Adding New Page to Resource (with parameter)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to add a few new pages to a rails resource that I am creating.

What I am doing in my routes file is as follows:

```
resources :users, :only => [:index, :show] do
    collection do
        get :show_subpage1
    end
end
```

When I look at my routes, show_subpage1 shows up, but not in the format I want. What shows  up in the routes is:

```
show_subpage1_users GET    /users/show_subpage1(.:format)
```

When what I WANT the route to be is:

```
show_subpage1_users GET    /users/:id/show_subpage1(.:format)
```

(with the ID).

How would I go about doing that in rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get:

> show_subpage1_users GET    /users/:id/show_subpage1(.:format)

do not define `:show_subpage1` as a `collection` route:

```
resources :users, :only => [:index, :show] do
  get :show_subpage1
end
```

or you could define it as a `member` route as follows:

```
resources :users, :only => [:index, :show] do
  member do 
    get :show_subpage1
  end
end
```

Also, I'm unsure why you have `:only => [:index, :show]` defined if you are also going to have a member route `:show_subpage1`.  I assume you do want to add add `:show_subpage1` to the `only` array, i.e.  `resources :users, :only => [:index, :show, :show_subpage1] do`.

Please take a read on "[Adding More RESTful Actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)"

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, @vee. Having it as a member is what I wanted, and works great. I have the :only, since I was originally using only RESTful routes, and didnt want some of the other actions.

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways with resources `member` or `collection`

```
resources :users, :only => [ :index, :show ] do
   # /users/:id/profile
   get 'profile', :on => :member
   # /users/profile
   get 'profile', :on => :collection
end
```

hope this helps